# Energy level degeneracy and conserved quantity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, noethers-theorem

Does the presence of degenerate energy levels necessarily indicate that there is a certain symmetry in the problem and that there is a conserved quantity?

Is the closure of the corresponding classical trajectories of motion obligatory?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. A degeneracy not associated with a specific symmetry is called [*accidental degeneracy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_energy_levels#Accidental_degeneracy).